# Better way to combine an array of two objects of the same type in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

So I've found a way to do this, but I think its rather ugly and a bit hacky.

I have a Contact model which contains a list of messages, my models can be seen below:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new Collection<Message>();
}

public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public string MessageContent { get; set; }

    public string Sender { get; set; }

    public string Receiver { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

what I wanted to do, and which I have done (badly) is combine the list of messages from both contacts models like by creating a viewModel containing a list of messages, and looping through the results of the contact messages and adding into the view model as seen below:

```
public class ContactMessageViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new Collection<Message>();
}


    public async Task<ContactMessageViewModel> GetContactMessages(string username, string contactName)
    {

        ContactMessageViewModel MessagesList = new ContactMessageViewModel();

        var messagesListUser = await _dbContext.Contact
            .Include(m => m.Messages)
            .Where(x =>
                                 (x.Owner == username) && x.Name == contactName).ToListAsync();
        
        var messagesListContact = await _dbContext.Contact
            .Include(m => m.Messages)
            .Where(x =>
                                 (x.Owner == contactName) && x.Name == username).ToListAsync();

        foreach(var message in messagesListContact)
        {
            foreach(var m in message.Messages)
            {
                MessagesList.Messages.Add(m);
            }
        }

        foreach (var message in messagesListUser)
        {
            foreach (var m in message.Messages)
            {
                MessagesList.Messages.Add(m);
            }
        }

        return MessagesList;

    }
```

This just feels super duper ugly to me, and I feel there is a better way to do this. I'm wondering if there is a better looking (and better performing) way to do this? Possibly just using linq?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the queries into a single query, and then return all the messages:

```
return new ContactMessageViewModel
{ 
    Messages = await _dbContext.Contact
        .Include(m => m.Messages)
        .Where(x => 
            (x.Owner == username && x.Name == contactName) ||
            (x.Owner == contactName && x.Name == username))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Messages)
        .ToListAsync()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do it in one query:

```
var messagesList = await _dbContext.Contact
      .Include(m => m.Messages)
      .Where(x => (x.Owner == username && x.Name == contactName)
       || (x.Owner == contactName && x.Name == username))
      .ToListAsync();
```

and use it to build `MessagesList.Messages`.

Or, if it is ok to get in results entries with `x.Owner == x.Name` (or such situations are impossible) you can do:

```
var names = new []{contactName, username};
var messagesList = await _dbContext.Contact
      .Include(m => m.Messages)
      .Where(x => names.Contains(x.Owner) && names.Contains(x.Name))          
      .ToListAsync();
```

**UPD**

It seems that you need only messages, so you can try something like this:

```
var messagesList = await _dbContext.Contact
      .Where(x => (x.Owner == username && x.Name == contactName)
         || (x.Owner == contactName && x.Name == username))
      .SelectMany(m => m.Messages)
      .ToListAsync();
// foreach m in messagesList MessagesList.Messages.Add(m);
```

Comment: 'fraid not! this returns two contact objects, what i'm after is a single list of the messages from those two objects

Comment: @AndyStav use `SelectMany` to flatten it.

Comment: use it where? can you provide an example?

Comment: @AndyStav I don`t fully understand what is the problem with this query I suggested? What is a problem to use it instead of `messagesListContact/messagesListUser` in one of your nested `foreach`  statements(and delete the other)?

Comment: than you for your reply but your answer does not make sense, MessagesList does not contain a definition for Messages so I do not understand what this is supposed to achiveve?

Comment: @AndyStav `MessagesList.Messages` is copy-pasted from your question)

Comment: ahh yes I did not realise you intended to keep that in, the naming conventions you wrote cofnused me as they are the same. this works providing i change my message from in my view model from collection to list, and then i am able to add range. I will accept this as answer, thank you Guru!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use something similar to the below which checks for either.

```
var messagesList = await (from c in_dbContext.Contact
                                                     from m in c.Messages
                                                    where (c.Owner == username && c.Name == contactName) || (c.Owner == contactName && c.Name == username)
                                                   select m).ToListAsync();
```

The code above assume owner and name will never be the same, otherwise you could store the username and contact name in an array and check the owner and name are both in the array.

The alternative is to store the `IQueryable<Messages>` in a variable, without doing a ToList. This won't hit the database until you need to enumerate. The benefit of this is you can manipulate the IQueryable and not hit the database until you need the items.